# notepad++ marking all lines containing number greater than 200000 and the line below

Tags: notepad++, bookmarks

I'm trying to mark all lines containing number greater than 200.000 after the phrase `"clap":` and the line below it.

```
02.10.19 12:51:  >> {"clip":15733,"clap":509478335,"flip":335,"flap":7348707420783}
12.16.17 13:15:  << {"clip_clap":1567,"flip_flap":hfyYHiJ86Fe3, "bing_bang":32642r1}
19.99.27 17:29: clip=clap, flip_flap
qwe
rty
uio
34.64.97 12:89:  >> {"clip":689,"clap":7458,"flip":35,"flap":4837834}
14.06.77 14:19:  << {"clip_clap":1570,"flip_flap":F7knH4tGHysd, "bing_bang":32u31}
37.33.21 45:97: bing_bang, snip=snap
asd
fgh
jkl
56.34.90 12:66:  >> {"clip":689,"clap":200003,"flip":45,"flap":3949827233}
48.77.23 97:33:  << {"clip_clap":157,"flip_flap":JyhG5uPoi2gR, "bing_bang":sjdbbk}
23.65.89 23:56: ping_pong, step=step
```

I want it to mark (bookmark) these lines:

```
02.10.19 12:51:  >> {"clip":15733,"clap":509478335,"flip":335,"flap":7348707420783}
12.16.17 13:15:  << {"clip_clap":1567,"flip_flap":hfyYHiJ86Fe3, "bing_bang":32642r1}

34.64.97 12:89:  >> {"clip":689,"clap":7458,"flip":35,"flap":4837834}
14.06.77 14:19:  << {"clip_clap":1570,"flip_flap":F7knH4tGHysd, "bing_bang":32u31}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

I tried to search for the digits over 6 `\d{6,}`, but I don't know how to make it mark only the numbers after the phrase `"clap":` and the entire line below that specific line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?"clap":(?:2\d{5}|\d{7}).+\R.+\R`
- **TICK** `Bookmark lines`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Mark all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
    .+?             # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    "clap":         # literally
    (?:             # non capture group
        2               # digit 2
        \d{5}           # 5 digits
      |               # or
        \d{7}           # 7 digits
    )               # end group
    .+              # 1 or more any character but newline
    \R              # any kind of linebreak
    .+              # 1 or more any character but newline
    \R              # any kind of linebreak
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]